# Did Rorshach know Edward Blake was the Comedian before the Comedian died?

Tags: dc, watchmen, watchmen-2009

In this scene, Rorshach enters the Comedian's penthouse hours after Edward Blake's death.

He discovers the Comedian's costume in a secret closet within Edward Blake's penthouse.

Did he know the Comedian's true name before that night?

Answers from either the comic book series or the movie are acceptable.

Comment: He gave him a [test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rorschach_test)? _ba-da-boom tish!_ (couldn't resist)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It appears that he did not.  On page 4 of the first issue of *Watchmen*, Rorschach appears in his civvies and is carrying his sign when he walks past the two police detectives that just finished looking over the Comedian's apartment.  They are discussing masked vigilantes—specifically Rorschach himself—which piques his interest in the crime scene the detectives had just left.

[image: Bottom of page 4]

On the next page, Rorschach finds the Comedian's badge—bloodstained, so Rorschach knows it is tied to the murder.  It appears that finding the button is what convinces Rorschach that the crime definitely needs further investigation.

[image: Top of page 5]

He is still mulling over the fact that the apartment definitely belonged to the Comedian as he lays out the dead man's costume; "Hurm," he mutters.

[image: Bottom of page 8]

The clincher, however, comes when Rorschach explains what he has found to his former partner.

> Investigated a routine homicide.  Victim named Edward Blake.  Found the costume in Blake's wardrobe.  **Seems he was the Comedian.**

[image: Middle of page 11]

Comment: Some heroes did know each others secret identities, Rorshach obviously knows Daniel Dreiberg is Nite Owl II to break into his house to inform him about the Comedian. The thing is that this is the exception not the norm for the new generation of heroes, Capt Metropolis introduces himself as Nelson Gardner at the botched creation of the Crimebusters but while the others recognize each other by their hero identities (Rorshach, Comedian, etc.) they do not know who is underneath the mask without further interactions. Nelson knows Eddie is the Comedian but doesn't volunteer this information.

Comment: @Gatchwar Rorshach knew about Daniel Dreiberg because Nite Owl II invited him to his lair several times before. The two of them worked together years ago to "clean up the gang problem".

Comment: @RichS I guess I worded that strangely, I knew they were partners I just mention the home invasion as that was the first overt interaction in the comics that showed Rorshach knew Nite Owl's secret identity, I'm unsure if Dan knows Rorshach's secret identity though. As stated in the answer Rorshach and Nite Owl didn't know the secret identity of the Comedian until Rorshach sees his costume at Eddie's. Among the Crime Busters I think only Capt Metropolis due to the Minutemen, Dr. Manhattan due to his non-linear time and maybe Silk Spectre II due to her mom knew who was behind the Comedian's mask